# Optimizing potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, riemannian-geometry, convex-optimization, poissons-equation

- Let $X$ be a vector field on a Riemmanian manfiold $M$.

I recently read that solving:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{argmin}_{\phi}\int_M (\nabla \phi - X)^2 d\mu, 
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is the Riemmanian measure thereon and $\phi$ is a scalar valued function thereon is *equivalent* to solving the PDE (poisson equation):
\begin{equation}
L\phi = Div(X),
\end{equation}
where $L$ is the Laplacian and $Div$ is the divergence operator.

- My question is if I want to solve a penalized optimization problem:
  \begin{equation}
  \operatorname{argmin}_{\phi}\int_M (\nabla \phi - X)^2 d\mu + \lambda C(\phi,X), 
  \end{equation}
  where $\lambda \in [0,\infty)$ and $C$ is a convex penalty function depending on the choice of $X$ and $\phi$, then is this equivalent to solving a certain PDE, which generalizes the poisson equation above?

Comment: Depends on the form of $C$, but typically yes: see [variational calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) and the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).

Comment: C itself is the convex envelope of the solution to a certain PDE (which i have not solved explicitly and it does not seem obvious how to)

Comment: I don't understand. In the question $C$ is a functional on scalar-valued functions, i.e. it maps any $\phi$ to a real number. How do you get from a convex function (on what? $M$?) to a functional? Do you mean something like $C(\phi) = \int c(\phi) d\mu$?

Comment: Yes exactly its the absolute value of the integral of the convex envelope of the solution to a certain PDE related to the embedding of M into a certain Euclidean space..